# getDisplayMedia giving error while running on Safari via extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension, screen-recording

I have an extension on safari, my aim is to perform tab/screen recording.

on button click I am running this below function:

```
async function startCapture() {
    logElem.innerHTML = '';

    try {
        videoElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
        dumpOptionsInfo();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error: ' + err);
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> Error: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent
> or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user
> denied permission.

Note: Permission for screen recording is enabled from preferences.

Million-dollar question is it possible to do **tab recording** in safari?

Comment: I have the same problem here, do you have your solution so far?